# Is this scenario thread safe in libgdx?

Tags: multithreading, libgdx

I am working on a game in libgdx, my partial scenario is this

> 1: I have got 5 squares which I fill every 10 second and once they all are full[50 sec] nothing is done. I fill them by coloring them to blue from red which is  by default.
>
> 2: A button which has its operations, one of those operations is that it will fill one of these square(color changed from red to blue.)

Here is the set up

> act(float)-------calls---> updateSquare
>
> updateSquare ---> checks whether it has been 10 second since last time, if yes then grab the first square available and change the color.
>
> buttonListener ----> change the color of the first square available to blue from red.

Now my question is that whether it is thread safe? Will these threads overlap with each other?

> Let's say my first two square are red and rest are blue so the first available is 3rd one, so if first **updateSquare** is called and than I click the **button** then two new squares will be turned blue and total four blue squares.
>
> However if both happen at the same time(updateSquare and buttonClick) then both of them will make only the 3rd square blue.

Is this scenario(overlap) possible? My friends it is not and I also don't face any problems like this, but I don't know whether it is thread safe or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this link](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling):

> Events are dispatched right before the call to ApplicationListener.render(), on the rendering thread.

What this means is that you actually do not have any multithreading here. All events (like the one your buttonListener receives) get collected during one frame. And they are dispatched to your handlers right before the next render call.

This is completely deterministic and there are no overlaps.